# How do you support PowerShell's -WhatIf & -Confirm parameters in a Cmdlet that calls other Cmdlets?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-cmdlet

I have a PowerShell script cmdlet that supports the `-WhatIf` & `-Confirm` parameters.

It does this by calling the `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess()` method before performing the change.
This works as expected.

The problem I have is that my Cmdlet is implemented by calling other Cmdlets and the `-WhatIf` or `-Confirm` parameters are not passed along to the Cmdlets I invoke.

How can I pass along the values of `-WhatIf` and `-Confirm` to the Cmdlets I call from my Cmdlet?

For example, if my Cmdlet is `Stop-CompanyXyzServices` and it uses `Stop-Service` to implement its action.

If `-WhatIf` is passed to `Stop-CompanyXyzServices` I want it to also be passed to Stop-Service.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some googling I came up with a good solution for passing common parameters along to called commands.  You can use the @ splatting operator to pass along all the parameters that were passed to your command.  For example, if

Start-Service -Name ServiceAbc @PSBoundParameters

is in the body of your script powershell will pass all the parameters that were passed to your script to the Start-Service command.  The only problem is that if your script contains say a -Name parameter it will be passed too and PowerShell will complain that you included the -Name parameter twice.  I wrote the following function to copy all the common parameters to a new dictionary and then I splat that.

```
function Select-BoundCommonParameters
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $BoundParameters
    )
    begin
    {
        $boundCommonParameters = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string, [Object]]'
    }
    process
    {
        $BoundParameters.GetEnumerator() |
            Where-Object { $_.Key -match 'Debug|ErrorAction|ErrorVariable|WarningAction|WarningVariable|Verbose' } |
            ForEach-Object { $boundCommonParameters.Add($_.Key, $_.Value) }

        $boundCommonParameters
    }
}
```

The end result is you pass parameters like -Verbose along to the commands called in your script and they honor the callers intention.

Comment: I had some trouble with this when I slotted it into some existing code - PSBoundParameters is actually of type System.Management.Automation.PSBoundParametersDictionary. I worked around this by building up an array of non-matching keys in an array and then calling $BoundParameters.Remove() to strip off the non-command parameters and then returning the modified PSBoundParameters in an end{} block.

Answer (score 19):

**Passing parameters explicitly**

You can pass the `-WhatIf` and `-Confirm` parameters with the `$WhatIfPreference` and `$ConfirmPreference` variables. The following example achieves this with [parameter splatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting):

```
if($ConfirmPreference -eq 'Low') {$conf = @{Confirm = $true}}

StopService MyService -WhatIf:([bool]$WhatIfPreference.IsPresent) @conf
```

`$WhatIfPreference.IsPresent` will be `True` if the `-WhatIf` switch is used on the containing function. Using the `-Confirm` switch on the containing function temporarily sets `$ConfirmPreference` to `low`.

**Passing parameters implicitly**

Since the `-Confirm` and `-WhatIf` temporarily set the `$ConfirmPreference` and `$WhatIfPreference` variables automatically, is it even necessary to pass them?

Consider the example:

```
function ShouldTestCallee {
    [cmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true,ConfirmImpact='Medium')] 
    param($test)

    $PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($env:COMPUTERNAME,"Confirm?")
}


function ShouldTestCaller {
    [cmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
    param($test)

    ShouldTestCallee
}

$ConfirmPreference = 'High'
ShouldTestCaller
ShouldTestCaller -Confirm
```

`ShouldTestCaller` results in `True` from `ShouldProcess()`

`ShouldTestCaller -Confirm` results in an confirm prompt even though I didn't pass the switch.

**Edit**

@manojlds answer made me realize that my solution was always setting `$ConfirmPreference` to 'Low' or 'High'. I have updated my code to only set the `-Confirm` switch if the confirm preference is 'Low'.

Comment: +1 for `$WhatIfPreference.IsPresent` . Not really sure if this can be used into a solution that the OP wants.

Comment: Used this to get a full solution. See my answer. Didn't know about $WhatIfPreference before, nice to know.

Comment: @Dan said he already had a script that supports the `-WhatIf` and `-Confirm` parameters. I didn't think I needed to write the other code as well.

Comment: `-Confirm` and `-WhatIf` will get inherited by commands you call.

Comment: Good answer, but these edits made the conclusion confusing and difficult to grasp. So, what's the correct way: `$ConfirmPreference.IsPresent` or rely on the passthrough mechanism of the preference variables?

Comment: @Alek, personally I prefer the pass-through mechanism (implicit passing of `-WhatIf` or `-Confirm`) to function and cmdlets. You do need to be aware of whether those switches are supported by each and/or wrap the the call to them with `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess()`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete solution based on @Rynant and @Shay Levy's answers:

```
function Stop-CompanyXyzServices
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true,ConfirmImpact='Medium')]

    Param(
        [Parameter(
            Position=0,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
        )]      
        [string]$Name
    )

    process
    {
        if($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($env:COMPUTERNAME,"Stop XYZ services '$Name'")){  
            ActualCmdletProcess
        }
        if([bool]$WhatIfPreference.IsPresent){
            ActualCmdletProcess
        }
    }
}

function ActualCmdletProcess{
# add here the actual logic of your cmdlet, and any call to other cmdlets
Stop-Service $name -WhatIf:([bool]$WhatIfPreference.IsPresent) -Confirm:("Low","Medium" -contains $ConfirmPreference)
}
```

We have to see if `-WhatIf` is passed separately as well so that the whatif can be passed on to the individual cmdlets. `ActualCmdletProcess` is basically a refactoring so that you don't call the same set of commands again just for the `WhatIf`. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I don't think you should be checking `"Low","Medium" -contains $ConfirmPreference`. Setting `-Confirm:$true` sets `$ConfirmPreference` to 'low', but your code will set `$ConfirmPreference` to 'Low' if it is 'Medium'. But I'm wondering if `-Confirm` and `-WhatIF` even need to be passed; see my edit.

Comment: @Rynant - They have to be so that it is done for each individual cmdlet AND for the custom cmdlet we are writing. So there will be multiple confirm.

Comment: Did you try my example? The function `ShouldTestCallee` confirms depending on whether or not `-Confirm` is used on `ShouldTestCaller` even though I don't pass the confirm parameter.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated per @manojlds comment**

Cast $WhatIf and $Confirm to Boolean and pass the values to the the underlying cmdlet:

```
function Stop-CompanyXyzServices
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true,ConfirmImpact='High')]

    Param(
        [Parameter(
            Position=0,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
        )]      
        [string]$Name
    )


    process
    {
        if($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($env:COMPUTERNAME,"Stop service '$Name'"))
        {                   
            Stop-Service $name -WhatIf:([bool]$WhatIf) -Confirm:([bool]$confirm)
        }                       
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? In cmdlet, I don't think so. And even the whatif output shows only for the custom cmdlet, which the OP already gets from the `ShouldProcess`

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. This was my initial solution as well, so I was hoping it would. Two issues - $WhatIf is not set even when you do `-WhatIf`. @Rynant's suggestion of `$WhatIfPreference.IsPresent` does work though. Also, since you are doing this within the if check of `ShouldProcess`, if it comes inside, `-WhatIf` will not be set anyway.

Comment: Not sure why It doesn't work for you. If I call the function without WhatIf or confirm, I get a confirmation, I press enter and the service stops. If I call the function with WhatIf, I get a whatif text. If I call it with Confirm, I get a confirmation, press enter, the service stops.

Comment: Hey, it works THAT way, but the OP is asking for confirmation and whatif for individual cmdlets. See my answer if it makes what I mean and what I think OP wants clear. Bascially, when i  give whatif, it should give whatif from our cmdlet, then whatif from each of the cmdlet being used.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you wont get run around the block for hours by this question and the answers here, I would suggest that you read this article instead:

https://powershellexplained.com/2020-03-15-Powershell-shouldprocess-whatif-confirm-shouldcontinue-everything/#suppressing-nested-confirm-prompts

The answers presented here does not work for many cases and I see a danger in people implementing the answers here, without understanding the fundamentals.

Here is how a hacked it to work across scriptmodules:
[image]