# Suppressing called function/cmdlet's WhatIf output, when that function has no WhatIf parameter

Tags: powershell

**TL;DR** - How do I specify `-WhatIf:$false` when a function/cmdlet does not have a `-WhatIf` parameter but still reacts to a `-WhatIf` in the parent call?

Consider the following slightly-contrived example:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Function Test-MyFunction {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true, ConfirmImpact='High')]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String] $Identity
    )

    $private:q = ($Identity -replace "'","''")
    if (Get-ADServiceAccount -Filter "sAMAccountName -eq '${private:q}'") {
        if (-not (Test-ADServiceAccount -Identity $Identity `
                                        -WarningAction 'SilentlyContinue' `
                                        -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'))
        {
            if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($Identity, 'Install')) {
                Install-ADServiceAccount -Identity $Identity
            }
            else {
                Write-Verbose "Skipped processing '$Identity'"
            }
        }
        else {
            Write-Verbose "Already registered '$Identity'"
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "'$Identity' does not exist"
    }
}
```

...and it's possible outputs:

```
PS> Test-MyFunction -Verbose -Identity 'nonexistent$'
WARNING: 'nonexistent$' does not exist

PS> Test-MyFunction -Verbose -Identity 'registered$'
VERBOSE: Already registered 'registered$'

PS> Test-MyFunction -Verbose -Identity 'notregistered$'
Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Install" on target "notregistered$"
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): n
VERBOSE: Skipped processing 'notregistered$'
```

If I add `-WhatIf` to those calls, you instead get the following:

```
PS> Test-MyFunction -WhatIf -Verbose -Identity 'nonexistent$'
WARNING: 'nonexistent$' does not exist

PS> Test-MyFunction -WhatIf -Verbose -Identity 'registered$'
What if: Performing the operation "Test" on target "CN=registered,CN=Managed Service Accounts,DC=contoso,DC=local"
What if: Performing the operation "Install" on target "registered$"
VERBOSE: Skipped processing 'registered$'

PS> Test-MyFunction -WhatIf -Verbose -Identity 'notregistered$'
What if: Performing the operation "Test" on target "CN=notregistered,CN=Managed Service Accounts,DC=contoso,DC=local"
What if: Performing the operation "Install" on target "notregistered$"
VERBOSE: Skipped processing 'notregistered$'
```

By specifying `-WhatIf` on *my* function call, it has passed that preference on the functions called by my function.  This is by design and, in most cases, what you would want.

For completeness, `Test-ADServiceAccount` is supposed to return `$true` or `$false` depending on whether a particular Managed Service has been installed to the local computer (at least, it does if you suppress its warnings/errors).

However, in this instance, due to the way `Test-ADServiceAccount` seems to have been written, if `-WhatIf` is supplied on *my* function call, it never actually performs the test, so always returns `$false`.  This means that my `if`/`else` logic is broken -- my function should *not* indicate that `Install-ADServiceAccount` would be called for `registered$` if `-WhatIf` was removed.

In normal circumstances, I would simply add `-WhatIf:$false` on to the end of the called function, but `Test-ADServiceAccount` does not expose its own `-WhatIf` parameter:

```
PS> Test-ADServiceAccount -WhatIf:$false -Identity 'registered$'
Test-ADServiceAccount : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'WhatIf'.
```

I appreciate that there are probably better ways to write the function, and that there is no harm really done here because `Install-ADServiceAccount` wasn't run anyway, but this function was intended as a MCVE, rather than something to be explicitly improved upon.  I also appreciate that `Test-ADServiceAccount` may not need `-WhatIf` semantics and probably shouldn't itself do `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess` (which I assume it is doing), but `ActiveDirectory` isn't my module and I don't see me changing its behaviour any time soon.

**In the general case**, how could I override the `-WhatIf` behaviour for a called cmdlet/function I don't control, from within my own function, when *my* function is called with its `-WhatIf` parameter and the *called* function does not expose its own `-WhatIf` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the `$WhatIfPreference` to `$false` before calling `Test-AdServiceAccount`. Afterwards you can restore the preference

```
    function Function1 {
        [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $true)]
        param (
        )

        $origWhatIfPreference = $WhatIfPreference.IsPresent

        $WhatIfPreference = $false
        Function2
        $WhatIfPreference = $origWhatIfPreference

        if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("target", "command")) {
            Write-Host "test"
        }
    }

    function Function2 {
        [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $true)]
        param (
        )
        if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("f2: target", "f2: command")) {
            Write-Host "f2: test"
        }
    }
```

Found `$WhatIfPreference.IsPresent` in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180271/how-do-you-support-powershells-whatif-confirm-parameters-in-a-cmdlet-that-c).

It seems that `Test-AdServiceAccount` detects the `WhatIf` switch in a dynamic way, e.g. via `$WhatIfPreference = $PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.GetValue('WhatIfPreference')`

**Update:**

Based on @Jessens comment, you can also wrap a specific function in a script block and invoke it `invoke-command { $WhatIfPreference = $false; Function2;}`, here you won't ne to reconstruct the old `$WhatIfPreference` state.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nice. You don't even need to unset it, the change will be local to the scope of `Function1`

Comment: @Moerwald / @MathiasR.Jessen - what is the distinction of `$WhatIsPreference.IsPresent` vs. plain `$WhatIsPreference`?  i.e. why does the value of `.IsPresent` infer truth, rather than the value of `$WhatIsPreference`.  If someone did `Test-MyCommand -WhatIf:$false` would `.IsPresent` be true?