# Why does my elseif block run when specifying -WhatIf

Tags: powershell, optional-parameters, powershell-5.1

I am having a bit of trouble *understanding* the documentation for [SupportsShouldProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-shouldprocess?view=powershell-7.1), and was looking to see if someone can break it down a little more for me to understand.

### Links used

- [MS-SupportsShouldProccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-shouldprocess?view=powershell-7.1)
- [Everything you wanted to know about ShouldProcess](https://powershellexplained.com/2020-03-15-Powershell-shouldprocess-whatif-confirm-shouldcontinue-everything/)
- [S.O. Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180271/how-do-you-support-powershells-whatif-confirm-parameters-in-a-cmdlet-that-c)

---

### Current Code

```
Function Test-ShouldProcess{
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [String[]]$Path = "C:\Users\Abraham\Desktop\FileToDelete.txt",
        [String[]]$ComputerName =  $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )
Begin{
$File = Get-Item -Path $Path 
}
Process{
    foreach($Computer in $ComputerName){
        try {
        #$PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction Stop

        if($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($Computer, "Removing: $File")){
            "$($file.Name) deleted"
    }
        elseif ($WhatIfPreference.IsPresent) {
            "Why does my what if switch go here?"
                }
            } catch [System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException] {
            "Unable to connect to $computer"
            "Error: $($error[0].Exception.Message.Split(':')[1].Trim())"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Question

In my `Process{}` block, I have an `if()`, and `elseif()` condition to check if `-Whatif` was specified.

- `Test-ShouldProcess -WhatIf`

I am having trouble understanding why my `elseif()` statement runs when specifying `-WhatIf` but, I get the message **in** my first `if()` condition:

> What if: Performing the operation "Removing: C:\Users\Abraham\Desktop\FileToDelete.txt.FullName" on target "DESKTOP-OEREJ77".

..yet, it doesn't run the code in that block only in my `elseif`. Would it not be the other way around?

*I'm aware im **explicitly** telling it to run that section if `-WhatIf` is specified (I know, kind of answers my question) but, im looking to see if there's something else to it. Seems like it would be the other way around.*

*Is this just an extra option for me?*

*Am I just thinking too much into this?*

Comment: `ShouldProcess` _always_ returns `$false` when `-WhatIf` is present - that's sort of the whole point, `-WhatIf` should _prevent_ execution of branches with irreversible side effects. The message is a side-effect of evaluating the _condition_ - something that _always_ happens (otherwise how would PowerShell know to enter the `if` block or not?)

Comment: The presence of `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess` ensures that you get the message from `-WhatIf`, but the `if` block never evaluates to true itself and doesn't execute. The only true condition is the `elseif` where you have added a check for whether the `$WhatIfPreference.IsPresent`. This gives it the illusion that both blocks run, but that is not the case as it never is with `if/elseif/else`. See `$a = 1; if ($a -eq 1) { "Y" } elseif ($a -eq 1) { "ELSEIF" } else { "Nothing to see here" }`

Comment: Ohhhhhhh, thats odd. Makes sense though! If one of you would like to post as an answer, I'd be glad to accept. Thank you guys, I can now die in peace. lol:)